# Use grep or sed to keep only the words that are in another word list file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, terminal, grep

I have a list of sentences (one sentence per line), and a dictionary (a list of words, one word per line). I want to use awk, grep or sed to edit the sentences file such that only the words that are in my dictionary file are kept.
For example, dictionary:

```
hello
dog
lost
I
miss
computer
buy
```

input file:

```
I miss my dog
I want to buy a new computer
```

result:

```
I miss dog
I buy computer
```

I know this can be done easily with Python but im trying to use the terminal commands (awk, sed, grep, or any other terminal command).

Thank you.

Comment: How would you do it in python? Adapt that to awk.

Comment: I know Python but I am a beginner to awk, sed, grep, etc. and trying to use them. In Python I would just read the word list file, create a list of strings with the words, then read the input file and output the word if it exists in the array.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Python I would just read the word list file, create a list of strings with the words, then read the input file and output the word if it exists in the array.

And that's how you'd do in in `awk` too:

```sh
$ awk 'FNR == NR { dict[$0] = 1; next } # Read the dictionary file
       { # And for each word of each line of the sentence file
         for (word = 1; word <= NF; word++) {
           if ($word in dict) # See if it's in the dictionary
             printf "%s ", $word
         }
         printf "\n"
       }' dict.txt input.txt
I miss dog
I buy computer
```

(This does leave a trailing space on each line, but that's easy to filter out if it matters)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { dict[$1]; next }
    {
        sent = ""
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($i in dict) {
                sent = (sent=="" ? "" : sent OFS) $i
            }
        }
        print sent
    }
' dict file
I miss dog
I buy computer
```

The ternary expression `(sent=="" ? "" : sent OFS)` is to ensure we don't get a spurious blank char at the start or end of the sentence that's going to be output by only adding a blank before the current word if there's already another preceding word.

The above assumes the matches should be case-sensitive. If not then change `dict[$1]` to `dict[tolower[$1]]` and `$i in dict` to `tolower($i) in dict`. It also assumes there's no punctuation to be accounted for, e.g. `I miss my dog.` or `my dog's friendly`. If that's wrong then edit your question to provide sample input/output that includes punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'H;$!d;x;s/.//;y/\n/|/;s/.*/s#\\b(&)\\b#\\n\&#g/' dictionaryFile |
sed -Ef - -e 's/^(\S+).*/\1/mg;s/\n/ /g;s/.//' textFile
```

Make the `dictionaryFile` into a sed command file, which prepends each word in that file by a newline.

In a second invocation of sed, use the sed command file piped from the first invocation, then using multiline substitution, remove everything in a line after the first word of a line.

Replace the newlines by spaces and remove the first first space at the beginning of a line and print the result.

Empty lines could be eliminated by adding `/\S/!d` to the second sed invocation commands.